Does Newton's third law give bouncing objects more energy?
I understand that this question seems nonsensical, so I will do my best to explain. When a ball, or any object, bounces, energy is conserved and converted to other forms like heat, sound, etc. However, when a ball hits the ground, wouldn't it gain energy from the reaction force pushing up on it? For instance, when the ball deforms, does it gain the energy from deformation because Newton's third law transferred the energy from the ground to the ball, or because its initial kinetic energy was converted to another form? Basically, I am just asking if a reaction force from one object transfers energy to the other, and if so, where does a ball gain energy from when it bounces? I am very confused on this topic and I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question. Thanks for the help.

When a ball bounces against a surface, mechanical energy is lost and then returned.  Consider vertical bounce against a horizontal surface to reduce complexity.  When that ball bounces, it must stop moving down before it can start moving up.  All kinetic energy is removed by the upward force acting on the downward-moving ball.  If no energy is lost due to the collision, if nothing is damaged or heated, if the ball is elastic, this kinetic energy goes into the elastic deformation that happens during the slowing of the ball.  This can happen even with a metal ball in an ideal situation.
The strength of the force stopping the ball, along with the ball's mass, decides the upward acceleration that stops the ball, the force opposing the downward motion is negative work and removes kinetic energy from the ball.  The elastic deformation of the ball stores this energy as potential energy.  The ball continues to feel upward force from the surface, but now the ball begins to move upward.  This speeds up the ball and adds kinetic energy to the ball.  This energy comes from the elastic potential energy stored in the temporary deformation.  The ball launches up from the surface at the same speed it was moving when it began to slow.  Although the whole process may seem instantaneous, the process of slowing/reversing/speeding up that happens while the ball is touching the surface does require a small amount of time and distance.

Essentially, is all the energy from the ball transferred to the ground because of the ground's upward force? Then, does the reaction force transfer more energy to the ball, not just in elastic energy but also sound and heat.

No , it doesn’t. Energy is conserved , when a ball for example is in a free fall and the ball is rigged so no energy will be taken up in deforming the ball, and there is no friction, then the ball kinetic energy at the moment of impact will be converted to potential energy after the bouncing which took effect due the reaction of the ground into the ball.hope it is clear

I will make it simple. You can do this experiment. Drop a ball from your desired height in free fall. Don't give any extra force to it. You would hear a sound wouldn't you? Where does this energy come from?
Coming directly to the point, it is true that in classical mechanics energy is conserved however it is also dissipated. The action-reaction pair are always there but there is a considerable loss of energy in that macroscopic interaction. The reason that the ball does not speed us is this. It transfers all of its energy to the ground (ALL of it) and the energy Given to the ball is by the ground but the energy of the ball decreases due to the sound, radiation as well as air resistance. But magnitude of action is always equal to the magnitude of reaction. So, there is an apparent loss of energy.
Yh, and coming back to the elastic energy point. If you deform a body before throwing it, and the body reforms during its course of travel, then the body has a net change of energy. But you have to apply the energy first, so actually you are giving an extra force. The very thing I forbade at first.
It's pretty much like quantum particles not in their vacuum state.
But when it comes to natural deformation. The body uses its own energy, so there is no increase in energy but a possibility (a HUGE possibility) of further energy loss.
Thank you.
With this I would rest my case.
